# рефакторинг okHttp к Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

Редактирую legacy - код. Хочу переписать на Retrofit

```
fun saveTicketPhoto(files: MutableList<File>, ticket_id: String): Response {

        val multipartBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

        for (i in files.indices) {
            multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("files[$i]", "file.png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), files[i]))
        }

        multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("ticket_id", ticket_id)

        val body = multipartBuilder.build()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(API_URL + "ticket/UploadFile")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            .post(body)
            .build()

        val response = client!!.newCall(request).execute()

        val str = response.body()!!.string()
        val o = JSONObject(str)

        val response1 = Response()
        response1.status = o.getBoolean("success")

        return response1
    }
```

Запросы отправляются через okHttp а ответ разбирается вручную.
Файлы собираются в MultipartBody. Имеется ли аналог в Retrofit, и если есть, то как в него собрать список файлов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891018/5479247, body запроса останется прежним.